# Wordpress: get_posts filter

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-fields

I am trying to create some filters in my posts with custom fields.
So in my `searchpage.php` I have added the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'cp_course', 'numberposts' =>-1,'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC', 's' => $searchterm,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'   => 'course_code',
            'value' => $code,
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'course_duration',
            'value' => $duration,
        )
    )
);

$course = get_posts($args);
```

But it won't work if I supply only `$code` or only `$duration`, I have to supply them both due to the `AND` relation. Is there a simpler way than multiple `IFs` to check if for example `$code` is not supplied then filter posts only by `$duration`

**EDIT**

By using [ash0ur solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52851353/10408255) I used this code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'cp_course', 'numberposts' =>-1,'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC', 's' => $searchterm,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'   => 'course_code',
                'value' => $code,
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'course_duration',
                'value' => $duration,
            ),          
        ),
        array(
        'key'   => 'course_duration',
        'value' => $duration,
        ),
        array(
        'key'   => 'course_code',
        'value' => $code,
        )
    )
);
```

But if I want to extend it to add more search terms I get to many `INNER JOIN` queries in the database which causes problem to the server. Here is what I ve tried which causes the issues:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'cp_course', 'numberposts' =>-1,'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC', 's' => $searchterm,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'   => 'course_code',
                'value' => $code,
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'course_duration',
                'value' => $duration,
            ),  
            array(
                'key'   => 'course_iteration_start',
                'value' => $date_from,
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'course_iteration_end',
                'value' => $date_to,
            ),  
        ),
        array(
        'key'   => 'course_duration',
        'value' => $duration,
        ),
        array(
        'key'   => 'course_code',
        'value' => $code,
        )
    )
);
```

Where `course_iteration_start` and `course_iteration_end` are `sub fields` (repeaters) of `course_iteration` `custom field`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested relation:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'   => 'course_code',
            'value' => $code,
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'course_duration',
            'value' => $duration,
        )
    ), 
    array(
        'key'   => 'course_duration',
        'value' => $duration,
    )
)
```

Comment: If you have many keys, so yes that will be slow, you will need to go with the if / else solution then or decrease the keys then filter after fetching from DB.

Comment: Can you provide an example with filtering after fetching from DB? thx